# Redirect to App Store from custom landing page (iOS)

Tags: branch.io

I have setup Branch.io links to open App if app is present and to redirect to our landing page if not. We have a parameter invite_id, which is used to customize our landing page.

We are showing our own get App button in our custom landing page that will take the user to our App in the Apple Store. We are including both the invite_id parameter and a _branch_match_id parameter we are seeing like this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app_name/idxxxxxxxx?invite_id=#{params[:invite_id]}&_branch_match_id=#{params[:_branch_match_id]}"
```

It works, but the parameters are not surviving the install when done this way. The invite_id is not present in the Branch.io data dictionary in the App Delegate.

How can I properly setup Branch.io links to work in a 2-step flow like this and still be able to pass params to app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you will want to integrate the [Branch Web SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking) on your custom landing page and replace the itunes link backing your button with the [Branch DeepviewCta()](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking#deepviewcta) function. Once you have done this, the app will receive the full set of parameters from the original Branch link (including your invite_id parameter) when the Branch SDK is initialized.